# MOVE instruction, assembly language, Nokia 68000 microprocessor

Tags: assembly, 68000

I'm studying the MOVE instructions for the 68k microprocessor. And I had this question in my textbook:

> If [D0.L]=$AAAABBBB, [$024020]=$FF,[$024021]=$EE,[$024022]=$DD,[$024023]=$CC, what are the contents of D0.L after execution of each one of the following instructions? (a) MOVE.B $024021, D0 (b) MOVE $024022, D0 (c) MOVE.L $024020, D0

I understand that in part (a) the answer is [D0.L]=$AAAABBEE since I'm only moving the contents of $024021 into the lowest bits of D0.L

I also understand that in part (c) the answer is D0.L=$FFEEDDCC since it will copy the contents of $024020-$024023.

But I don't understand part (b). I think the teacher said that the answer is D0.L=$AAAABBCC, but perhaps I heard wrong.

Also, I wrote a code to check my results:

```
           ORG         $24000       ; Go to address 24000
           MOVE.L      #$AAAABBBB,D0; 
           MOVE.B      #$FF,$24020;
           MOVE.B      #$EE,$24021;
           MOVE.B      #$DD,$24022;           
           MOVE.B      #$CC,$24023;
           MOVE.B      $24021,D0 ;     
           MOVE        $24022,D0 ;     
FINISH     JMP         FINISH    ;
```

However, the contents of $24023 are always #$EE, even though in my program it says that it should be #$CC.

Comment: Make sure you don't overlap your code and data. `ORG $24000` is perilously near the `$24020` ... I believe the correct answer is `$AAAADDCC`

Comment: @Jester Thank you! Yeah, it seems like the problem with my code was the first line (overlapping code and data). And now the program says that the answer is `$AAAADDCC` which, like you said, seems to be the right answer. Thanks again!